# How to change the codes into swapping pointers instead of using "temp" pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers

below is a part of my codes where I have done for the Selection Sort using linked list. However, I've asked my tutor and he told me to change the code by not using "temp" but swap the pointers instead. Therefore, I'm seeking for help here on how to not use the temp but change it into swapping the pointers? :) Thanks.

```
void List::SelectionSort(){
nodePtr last = NULL;
int temp = 0;
int max = 0;
count = 0;
count = CalculateData();


while(count > 1){
    curr = head;
    nodePtr Biggest = NULL;
    Biggest = curr;
    max = curr->data;

    for(int i=0; i<count-1; i++){
        if(max < curr->data){
            max = curr->data;
            //cout << "biggest data" << max << endl;
            Biggest = curr;
        }

           // cout << "biggest data" << max << endl;
           // cout << "curr data" << curr->data << endl;
            curr = curr->next;
            last = curr;
    }//end for
    if(last->data > max){
       max = last->data;
    }

    if(Biggest->data == max){
        temp = last->data;
        last->data = max;
        Biggest->data = temp;
        GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo( hstdout, &csbi );//color only ignore this
        SetConsoleTextAttribute( hstdout, 0x1B ); //color only ignore this
        cout << "swapped " << Biggest->data << " with " << last->data << endl;
        SetConsoleTextAttribute( hstdout, csbi.wAttributes );//color only ignore this
    }else{
        GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo( hstdout, &csbi );//color only ignore this
        SetConsoleTextAttribute( hstdout, 0x1B ); //color only ignore this
        cout << "swapped " << last->data << " with " << last->data << endl;
        SetConsoleTextAttribute( hstdout, csbi.wAttributes );//color only ignore this
    }

//cout << "count " << count << " ";
//cout << "last " << last->data << " ";
//cout << "biggest " << Biggest->data << endl;

PrintData();
cout << endl;
count--;

}//end while
cout << endl;
```

}

Comment: This is much easier if you take out your pencil and paper and draw what you need to do before using the keyboard. (The swapping itself will use exactly the same method, but if the elements are big, swapping the pointers is much more efficient.)

Comment: ya I did what you suggest, but still couldn't make it work and that's why my question appears here :v

Answer (score 1):

To swap the pointers, you need pointers to the pointers.  So you need to work mainly with `nodePtr*` rather than `nodePtr`

You need to start out from head with something such as:
`nodePtr* curr = &head;`
then you would mostly use `(*curr)` instead of `curr`
You would advance the pointer with `curr = &(*curr)->next;`

Once you have pointers to the pointers that you need swapped, you can swap them with std::swap()

Answer (score 1):

in this code:

```
temp = last->data;
last->data = max;
Biggest->data = temp;
```

you are swapping data, and not nodes of your list. Your tutor wants you to swap nodes. This means you must relink your list. I don’t know how your node is defined; if it is a doubly-linked list then it's quite easy, in this case it should look like:

```
nodePtr biggestPrev = Biggest->prev;
nodePtr biggestNext = Biggest->next;

// this pseudocode puts Biggest in place of last
nodePtr tmp = last->prev->next; 
last->prev->next = Biggest;
Biggest->prev = last;
Biggest->next = tmp;
tmp->prev = Biggest;

// This pseudocode puts last in place of Biggest
biggestPrev->next = last;
last->prev = biggestPrev;
bigestNext->prev = last;
last->next = biggestNext;
```

this is a pseudocode, no terminal cases (such as null nodes) are considered. If your list is singly-linked then it's more work; you will need to iterate the list and decide which elements to re-link.

Comment: If you look at the way head was used, you can see that your solution for a doubly linked list would not work even if it were a doubly linked list (because head is a pointer not a node and points to the real first node, not a dummy).  That use of head would be rather lame for a doubly linked list anyway, so more likely it is a singly linked list.

Comment: @JSF I am not sure if I understand you, both Biggest and last are of type nodePtr, and are pointers. Also I assume this is the correct place to do the swapping.  OP asked what kind of swapping is tutor asking for, so my answer is giving - maybe not exact answer - but a hint how to solve this. The rest of homework is left to OP.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not going to give you code, but an illustration.
(Writing the code is good practice and not very difficult.)

Here's a picture of two parts of a list, before and after switching the places of A and B:

[image]

As you see, you need to swap two pairs of pointers, not one.
(Swapping the pointers makes more sense when the elements are bigger than integers.)

Comment: Thank you. :) all I need is guideline, I wish I could do it myself.

Answer (score -1):

In a selection sort, you choose an element to move. Since this is an array, the elements you are moving are the nodes, not the data in the nodes. You don't need to swap. Arguably, this makes your selection sort behave more like insertion sort, but really you are just leveraging the properties of the data structure.

So on a high level:

```
SelectionSort(inputList)
    outputList : initially empty
    while not empty(inputList)
        (biggestNode, predecessor) = findBiggestNode(inputList)
        removeNode(inputList, biggestNode, predecessor)
        insertAtHead(outputList, biggestNode)
    inputList = outputList
```

Some high level C++ code:

```
// Find biggestNode and its predecessor
biggestNode = head;
predecessor = &head;
curr = &head->next;
while (*curr) {
    if ((*curr)->data > biggestNode->data) {
        biggestNode = *curr;
        predecessor = curr;
    }
    curr = &(*curr)->next;
}

/* Removing biggestNode */
*predecessor = biggestNode->next;

/* Insert biggestNode to head of output */
biggestNode->next = outHead;
outHead = biggestNode;
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](http://ideone.com/5xDYQA)

Comment: Thanks everyone for giving me guideline. :)